# mysql handlersocket config

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, handlersocket

I am trying to configuration a `handlersocket` plugin.
I install the plugin and it is visible in mysql by show plugins;
DAEMON handlersocket.so but I can't reach the needed variable in mysql.

- [this is my.cnf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCzev.jpg)
- next, i restart mysql: [restart mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKyp1.jpg)
- and than show variable list in mysql:[mysql variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFvpD.jpg)

And as you can see there no needed variables set

I am using:

ubuntu 16.04 tls
mariadb

Comment: Is this a programming question or a server admin question or a database-admin question?

Comment: i suppose it is server admin and database-admin scope

Comment: Probably better to roll it over to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).